# OnClick start timer based on input type value entered

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer, onclick

I have used this [Time picker](https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/)  script for input type,and time picker value is coming like this:

[image: Input type value]

And i have a timer ,Timer 2000sec static now and i want to make it dynamic.
[image: Timer 2000sec static now and i want to make it dynamic]
The script of the timer is this:

```
var gdTimer = new Countdown({
time:2000, 
//time:$("#gd_time").val(),  
//Id of the input value time-picker coming as shown in image format "01:05"
rangeHi:"hour",
numbers     :   {
    color   : "#FFFFFF",
    rounded : 0.15 
}
});
```

I want to replace the time:2000, statics to dynamic ,the input value is is coming with **"hours:minutes"** i want to read that value into **seconds**,

Example the Image-1 shows the `01 hours and 05 minutes` so the timer should be `18000 seconds`

if any alternate ways are there for this problem please suggest

Comment: So read the input value convert it to seconds. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution other than taking the value of `gd_time` and just passing it into a function that returns the value represented as seconds?

Comment: 1 hour and 5 minutes is only 3900 seconds though. Not sure how you're getting 18,000.

Comment: So you do not know how to read the input's? Select it by id/class/attribute and read the value.